# Associativity of Filter Expression in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some confuse about the associativity of filter expression in XPath.
Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:function name="my:func" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:message select="'my func enter'"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="('apple', 'orange')"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="my:func()[.!='apple']"/>
<!--     <xsl:sequence select="my:func()[false()]"/>-->

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this stylesheet, the result tree is: 'orange', the message output is: 'my func enter'. That's OK.

But if I comment:

```
<xsl:sequence select="my:func()[.!='apple']"/>
```

and uncomment:

```
<!--     <xsl:sequence select="my:func()[false()]"/>-->
```

Then nothing output (including result tree and message output).

I am now confuse about the associativity of filter expression.

Right or Left?

Why no message output in my:func?

Comment: Good question. I don't think the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-filter-expression uses the term associativity, it simply explains the result of a filter expression. I think the result you get for the `my:func()[false()]` is correct, whether the optimizer is allowed to infer that evaluating the function is not necessary and to directly return an empty sequence is something I can't answer, hopefully @MichaelKay gives you his estimation later on.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-errors-and-opt has some explanation about allowed optimization, it says for instance "An implementation is always free to evaluate the operands of an operator in any order".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath 3.1 specification says in §2.3.4

*Consider an expression Q that has an operand (sub-expression) E. In general the value of E is a sequence. At an intermediate stage
during evaluation of the sequence, some of its items will be known and
others will be unknown. If, at such an intermediate stage of
evaluation, a processor is able to establish that there are only two
possible outcomes of evaluating Q, namely the value V or an error,
then the processor may deliver the result V without evaluating further
items in the operand E.*

In the case of an expression `E[P]`, where `P` is known to be `false()` for all items in `P`, it is known before evaluating the first item in `E` that the only possible outcomes of the expression (as a whole) are an empty sequence or an error; and therefore the processor may deliver an empty sequence without evaluating any items in `E`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I generally understand the intent of the specification. But there are still 3 questions I want to confirm: (1) does xsl:message be treated as a dynamic error? (2) Can I use this mechanism to simulate if expression in XPath safely? (3) Parentheses do not work (eg: (my:func())[false()] still output nothing), is it work normally.

Comment: (1) the effect of xsl:message is essentially implementation-defined. A message isn't an error unless you use terminate=yes, but it's essentially up to the implementation whether or not you see any messages, where they go, what order they appear in, and how they are formatted.

Comment: (2) No. An 'if' expression gives you a guarantee that a branch won't be executed if the condition is false (respectively true). The "errors and optimization" rules leave it all to the implementation.

Comment: (3) There is no reason why parentheses should affect the outcome. The only way to force the filtered expression to be evaluated is to ensure that the value of the predicate can't be predicted in advance. For example use an xsl:param initialized to false.

Comment: Thank you for answering my stupid questions without being tired of it! About (3), I use an global xsl:param initialized externally to false(), it still nothing output. The Saxon processor always try to predicte filtered expression in advance if no use context item, so it seems can't be enforced.

Comment: Yes, for Saxon you would also need to ensure that the value of the predicate appears to depend on the context item, e.g. `f:x()[string-length(.) gt 100000000]`. But really, the answer is to avoid writing code that depends on side-effects: find a different way to structure your stylesheet.